# Eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm getting the error `Parsing error: Unexpected token ..` from **eslint** for this snippet. What's wrong with that?

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
        if (loggingIn) return <div></div>
        return !authenticated
            ? (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated }))
            : (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }} />
)
```

Comment: My guess is that you didn't configure eslint to handle the spread/rest property proposal. http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to configure eslint to use the right parser for your project. If you're using babel you'll need babel-eslint:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

And then add this to your .eslintrc file:

```
{
  ...
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

If you're not using babel check out http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options for other options.